# direct file transfer between two remote windows servers

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I want to transfer large amount of data from server 1 to server 2.  I can mount both servers on my local linux PC using smb or cifs. I can also mount them on my local windows PC. I cannot ssh any of the servers. To gain speed, I would like to avoid that the data transit through my local computer. Is it possible?

Comment: You have described **only** how to connect the two servers thru the intermediary of your Linux  or Windows pc. How do you expect that **not** to go thru your local machine? You can avoid passing thru your local machine **iff* server 1 connects directly to server 2, not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae. This is what I wanted to know (hence my question : is it possible?)

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have network connectivity between the two servers, you can set up any kind of file server, including Windows' native FTP server to allow transfer to/from the servers.

Only one server needs a file server installing, the other just needs a client to allow bi-directional file transfer.